# Random scrollable page?

Tags: html, css, scrollable

Me and my friend are making a new site, and we are both beginners in HTML and CSS.
I made this site to test things, but there is a problem.
I can scroll while this isn't suposed to be.

Index.html page:

```
<html>
<title>ClipOfTheDay</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta name="disrciption" content="Welcome to ClipOfTheDay, the awesome website where you can see your favourite clips every day!">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<br>
<center><p><i><font color="#989898" face="times, serif" size="6">
Welcome to Clip Of The Day!
</font></i></p></center>
<br>
<hr>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<p><i><font color="#989898" face="times, serif" size="4">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 24%; top: 22%; height: 80%; width: 80%">Music Video</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 73%; top: 22%; height: 80%; width: 80%">Funny Video</div>         
</font><p><i>
<Br>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 12%; top: 30%; height: 80%; width: 80%"><iframe width="420" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/McEoTIqoRKk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 60%; top: 30%; height: 80%; width: 80%"><div id="header"><iframe width="420" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fZfH6Dt_E3k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></pre></div>
<br>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 70%; height: 80%; width: 80%"><p><i><font color="#989898" face="times, serif" size="2">&copy; All rights reserved ClipOfTheDay
            </font></i></p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My style.css

```
body
{
background-image:url('Background.jpg');
}

hr
{
color: #505050;
background-color: #505050;
height: 0,5px;
}

br {
        line-height: 80%;
     }

{ 
    position: relative; 


html 
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
clip: auto;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope you guys can help us!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the height in hr should not use a comma as a decimal point. `height:0.5px` would solve the problem

Secondly, there is an unused(?) section
`{ 
    position: relative;`
In the code. That bugs the lower section of html, failing the whole stylesheet.

It should work if it is fixed.

Comment: Sir, you are fantastic! Managed to get the side away scroll gone. Now I can still scroll downwards, I don't want that either!
You can check the site here : http://www.clipoftheday.pixub.com/

Comment: Oddly, It doesn't scroll downwards here.

Comment: It does at my screen, and still got tons of questions.. I know everyone has different resolutions, I got 2 screens myself. The text above the youtube vids isn't at the same place on both screens. You know how to fix that?

Comment: It should be the problem of the positions. You used percentages for the positions, which depends on the window size. But for the problem of scrolling, I can't tell because I don't see such problem here. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using google chrome, but can you help me with the percentages? I need to change it to pixels right?